# HTML Form appearing on button press

Tags: html, forms

I am a newbie to web development so sorry for my stupidity. I am actually creating a local website and I wanted to make a user profile page on that website. What I want to accomplish is that the profile page should be not be editable in the normal use case but when the user presses the Edit button (like in facebook), the fields become editable and a save button appears (basically a form but without reloading the page or any server side work). The user then updates the fields and saves. The save request will be sent to the server to update the database (can that somehow be done without reloading the page too ? i see facebook page does not reload when you edit and save).

So that is it. Waiting for a reply.

P.S. I think some javascript code will come to my rescue.

Comment: Mark all your inputs with "readonly" (they won't be editable) and hide the submit button. In the onclick of the edit button remove that attribute from inputs and make the submit button visible.

Comment: In general, it's good to include some information about what you've actually tried. As your question is formulated, you're basically asking someone else to do the work for you - which is not what this site is for. Just a tip ;)

Comment: We would need to see what code you already have and advise you accordingly as to what steps to take next etc.

Comment: Okay thanks everyone for the replies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a very general question, so I can't do anything but give a general answer. I would highly recommend you learn [jQuery](http://jquery.com/).

jQuery makes it easy to manipulate the HTML and CSS from Javascript - which you'll need to do in order to show/hide the content and the forms for editing the content (or otherwise manipulate the code on the page in order to achieve what you want - there are various ways to do this, adriano's comment on your question lays out a good solution).

The specific part about sending such requests in the background is called AJAX, and jQuery has support for that too.